# Get the port Actor is listening on

Tags: scala, actor

How can I get the port the Actor is listening on?

I have the following code

```
import scala.actors.Actor
import scala.actors.Actor._
import scala.actors.remote.RemoteActor._

object DispatchActor extends Actor 
{
  def act() 
  {
    alive(8888)
    register('myService, self)
    println("Listening on port " + howToGetPort)

 ..

  }
}
```

How can I print the port which the Actor is listening on?

The second question is about calling the alive() and register() methods. These methods are defined in RemoteActor object. How is it possible to call them on an Actor object.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the Actor API gives you any way to know which port a particular Actor is listening on (a bit similar to Java RMI now I think of it) so the standard approach in this case is to remember what port you specified when you called `alive`.

As far as the second part of your question goes, you are not calling the methods 'on' your Actor object, you have already imported the relevant defintions from RemoteActor at the top of your object definition - so you could write your code like this:

```
import scala.actors.Actor
import scala.actors.Actor._
import scala.actors.RemoteActor

class DispatchActor(port: Int) extends Actor 
{
  def act() 
  {
    RemoteActor.alive(port)
    RemoteActor.register('myService, self)
    println("Listening on port " + port)
  }
}
```

Note that I've changed your object definition to a class definition to allow it to be parameterised.

Comment: Interesting. So can we think of alive() and register() as static methods in RemoteActor?

Comment: If you're coming from Java-land, yes, kind of. Methods in Scala are always attached to an object, these are actually methods on the singleton object RemoteActor.